# could not access laravel object data

Tags: laravel

```
$cntct = DB::table('products') 
            ->join('merchants','merchants.id','=','products.merchant_id') 
            ->where('products.id',$id)
            ->get();

dd($cntct[0]->address);die;
```

data show from this query

```
"{
    "address":"dummy"
    "state":"dummy",
    "zip":"45345",
    "country":"Pakistan",
    "city":"dummy"
}"
```

I want access this address but when i write `dd($cntct[0]->address->address);die;`
error show

> Trying to get property 'address' of non-object

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, change the

```
->get()
```

to

```
->first()
```

Cuz you only want one value (you give the products id)

And then

```
dd($cntct->address);  // no need of die
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `foreach ($cntct as $item){ //your code  }`.
Maybe the query does not return any result and that's the cause of an error  - Trying to get  property 'address' of non-object.